# Why drawContours Max returns empty in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to draw the largest contour of this image. But my code always returns a blank image. So, I am more than grateful of your help to solve this issue.

Original image
[image]

Here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_1 = cv2.imread('img.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get external contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(img_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

maxcontour = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, default=0)


# draw white filled contour on black background
contour = np.zeros(img_1.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
contour.fill(0)
mask1 = cv2.drawContours(contour, [maxcontour], 0, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow('mask1.png', mask1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find contours beings by looking for white objects on black background. Since the background of your image is white, the entire image gets detected as a top-level contour. This contour is as large as the image itself, so it comes first in the sorted array. That's why you see (or rather would, if you had a `cv2.waitKey()` there) a big blue rectangle. | The simplest thing is to invert the input to `findContours` -- make the first parameter `255 - img_gray`.

Comment: BTW, the `contour.fill(0)` is rather pointless, since in previous statement you constructed contour with `np.zeros` -- it's full of zeros already. And as I mentioned above, your `imshow` is missing an associated `waitKey`, so the GUI won't work, and since your `imshow` is the last statement of the script, the program will just exit instead of displaying anything.

Comment: @DanMašek Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find contours search for a white objects so just invert the image colors:

```
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(img_gray)
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```